# Styling class element with python/selenium

Tags: python, css, selenium

I want to style **min-height** of an element in **python**
i have this:

```
<div class="myclass"></div>
```

i tried this:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('myclass').css('min-height', '10000px');")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0].style.minHeight = '1000px'
```

class name will return multiple elements